# Jquery UI Slider multiple start

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

I am working on a template that could have one or more JQuery UI Sliders.

Can I initialize all sliders from a single script if the settings for each are held within a data-options or data-id attribute on the input?

HTML would be something like:

```
<label for="amount">Amount <input type="text" id="amount" data-id="5000" class="ui-slider-input" readonly />
  <div class="max-slider"></div>
</label>
```

I have it doing a single element like this:

```
var sliderInput = $('#amount');
var sliderDiv = sliderInput.next('.max-slider');
var sliderMax = sliderInput.attr('data-id');
sliderDiv.slider({
  range: "min",
  value: sliderMax,
  min: 0,
  max: sliderMax,
  step: 10,
  slide: function( event, ui ) {
    sliderInput.val( ui.value );
  }
});
sliderInput.val( sliderMax ) );
```

But I would like to initialize multiple sliders, each with a different max and step value.

Comment: Could you show a snippet of HTML that includes more than one slider element, then you will - hopefully - get a solution that's specifically relevant to your situation, and it saves us from creating a second slider... :)

Comment: @DavidThomas The second or third slider would be identical aside from the id and data-id

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can just iterate with `each()`

```
var options = {
    range : "min",
    min   : 0,
    step  : 10,
    slide : function( event, ui ) {
        $(this).prev().val( ui.value );
    }
}

$('.sliders').each(function() {
    $(this).slider(
        $.extend({}, options, {
            value : $(this).data('id'),
            max   : $(this).data('id'),
        })
    );
});
```

Comment: Can you show this working in a fiddle? When I try the value no longer changes when sliding.

Comment: Thanks, this works so far. I have updated the [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/zxtur473/2/) to be closer to my needs. Can you tell me what I am doing wrong with the max and step values?

Comment: You have arrays in the attribute, but you probably wanted objects -> https://jsfiddle.net/adeneo/zxtur473/3/

Comment: Great thanks, I knew I was missing something obvious!

Comment: Sorry I thought it was working, but it is actually giving `TypeError: alignValue.toFixed is not a function` while sliding and the sliding is not consistant...?

Comment: The error seems to be from passing strings , try this -> https://jsfiddle.net/zxtur473/4/

Comment: I don't understand why adding the + helps, but it works, thanks again.